# Scss formatting in VSCode for Vue

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, prettier, vetur

I messed up my VSCode settings and now I can't get SCSS formatting back. It doesn't work nor for Vue SFC `<style lang="scss" />` nor for plain SCSS files. I have Vetur installed and no Prettier.
Here are my VSCode settings:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 12.5,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/package-lock.json": true,
    "/package-lock.json": true,
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/nuxt": true
  },
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/nuxt": true
  },
  "webhint.enableTelemetry": "disabled"
}
```

Would be soo thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I've broke `.prettierrc` with a non-existing rule.